# String to array without explode

Tags: php, curl

I am using an api to retrieve data from another server the data returned is something like this:

```
accountid=10110 type=prem servertime=1263752255 validuntil=1266163393 
username= curfiles=11 curspace=188374868 bodkb=5000000 premkbleft=24875313
```

This is a whole string I need two values out of whole string, I am currently using preg_match to get it, but just to learn more and improve my coding is there any other way or function in which all values are automatically convert to array?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using explode is the fastest for this, no matter what.

However, to answer you question, you can do this many ways. But just because you can, doesn't mean you should. But if you really wanna make it weird, try this.

**UPdated using strpos**

```
$arr = array();
$begin = 0;
$str = trim($str); # remove leading and trailing whitespace
while ($end = strpos($str, ' ', $begin)) {
    $split = strpos($str, '=', $begin);
    if ($split > $end) break;
    $arr[substr($str, $begin, $split-$begin)] = substr($str, $split+1, $end-$split-1);
    $begin = $end+1;
}
```

Comment: What's that manual iteration through a string? Strpos might be more cryptic, but it's a gazillion times faster.

Comment: One thing keep the habit of assigning values to a variable, because I will check strlen each time it loops

Comment: I am trying to print_r and echo $arr but no values printed just Array ( )

Answer (score 1):

Sooo, my faster-than-`preg_split`, strpos-based function looks like this:

```
function unpack_server_data($serverData)
{
    $output = array();
    $keyStart = 0;
    $keepParsing = true;

    do
    {
        $keyEnd = strpos($serverData, '=', $keyStart);
        $valueStart = $keyEnd + 1;
        $valueEnd = strpos($serverData, ' ', $valueStart);
        if($valueEnd === false)
        {
            $valueEnd = strlen($serverData);
            $keepParsing = false;
        }

        $key = substr($serverData, $keyStart, $keyEnd - $keyStart);
        $value = substr($serverData, $valueStart, $valueEnd - $valueStart);
        $output[$key] = $value;

        $keyStart = $valueEnd + 1;
    }
    while($keepParsing);

    return $output;
}
```

It looks for an equals character, then looks for a space character, and uses these two to decide where a key name begins, and when a value name begins.

Comment: Your function has error only 1st value of string is converted as key.

Comment: I tried with the string you provided us and it yields good results. Did you test with this string too? If you didn't, can you post the one you used?

Answer (score 0):

try out [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) maybe you need to do `str_replace(' ', '&', $string);` before

Comment: Won't work. `parse_str` (not parse-str) expects ampersands as key-value separators.

Comment: well thats why he needs to str_replace() it

Comment: That wasn't there when I commented. (And it's going to fail if his user strings can contain ampersands.)

Comment: yes thats true, maybe it would help if he first "masks" the text ampersands with str_replace('&', 'crazychar', $string) and after parse_str replace it back.

Comment: That's getting into a lot of trouble for using a function that wasn't designed to do what you're making it do.